# Checkout a complete Subversion tree excluding tags/ and branches/

Tags: bash, svn, version-control, cmd, branch

I'm working on a corporate source code tree that contains 100s of Maven sub-projects. Since each sub-project has its own layout of `branches/` and `tags/` sub-folders, the entire tree is laid out something like this:

```
root/
    some/intermediate/dirs/
        project1/
            branches/
                ...
            tags/
                ...
            trunk/
                ...
        project2/
            branches/
                ...
            tags/
                ...
            trunk/
                ...
        ...
        projectN/
            branches/
                ...
            tags/
                ...
            trunk/
                ...
    other/intermediate/dirs/
        projectN+1/
            ...
```

I need to check out the `trunk/` versions of all the projects but unfortunately, the command `$ svn co protocol://path/to/repo/root/` checks out complete versions of tags and branches leaving me with thousands of redundant source trees and taking ***forever***.

Moreover, `N` is a very large number and it is not practicable for me to go in and check out each project's trunk individually.

Is there an `svn` command that will enable me to skip `tags/` and `branches/` trees?

I found [a blog that explains how to write a Java program to accomplish this using the SVNKit](http://blog.bangbits.com/2011/03/svn-checkout-without-branches-and-tags.html) but I was hoping I could get it done using a one-liner from the command line.

**Update**: A solution using only the `svn` executables is preferred, but if some shell scripting is needed, I would prefer a Windows batch script or, failing that, any `bash` or `zsh` script would do...

Comment: Can you add the shell that you're using as a tag?  I think you're looking for something for Linux/Unix but I'm not sure.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk, updated. Prefer Windows but any `bash` or `zsh` script would do in a pinch...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is [SVN sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

You'll want a skeleton structure, and fill in only the `trunk`s when you get to them.  Something like (Bourne shell syntax):

```
svn co --depth empty protocol://path/to/repo/root/
for in in some intermediate dirs; do svn up --set-depth empty $i; cd $i; done
svn up --depth immediates .
for i in *; do svn up --depth infinity $i/trunk; done
```

I'm assuming none of the directories in question contain spaces or shell metacharacters - add appropriate quoting if necessary.

Beware when using sparse directories - it's easy to lose track of what's excluded and what doesn't actually exist...

Comment: For me in Windows' `cmd.exe`, the following worked for the for loop:

`for /D %d in (*) do svn up --depth infinity %d\trunk`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `--set-depth empty` I [found](https://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/288) suggestion use `--set-depth=exclude`. F.e.:

```
svn update --set-depth=exclude <foldername>
```

It much more convenient. If in your example you do in directory `some/intermediate/dirs/project1/`:

```
svn up --set-depth empty tags
```

And then:

```
svn up
```

Directory `tags` will be appeared again and all content will be downloaded. So you need made updates from descendant directories only.

But with:

```
svn update --set-depth=exclude tags
```

**Directory will be deleted, and you may do `svn up` even from `root/` directory**! Update will come only to leaved directories!

To restore initial state and return all deleted in that way directories you may do:

```
svn up --set-depth infinity .
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, which output format you need, but this batch line may help:

```
dir /s /b /ad |findstr /v /R "\<tags\>  \<branches\>"
```

`findstr` can search for "words" with `"\<word\>"`, so `moretags`or `tagsmore` will not be excluded. See `findstr /?`

or if you are only interested in *trunk" subdirectories:

```
dir /s /b /ad |findstr  "\<trunc\>"
```

Answer (score -1):

A colleague (Knut) came up with this simple bash script, which checkouts the whole tree but without tags and branches. You can easily and quickly search there in the local copy:

## bash function "checkout":

```
   function checkout() {
                 local base=${1%%/}
                  echo "checkout($base)"
                  for x in $(svn list $base); do
                    #echo "base=$base x=$x"
                    if [ "$x" = "trunk/" ]; then
                      echo $base
                      svn co $base/trunk ${base##*/}
                    elif [[ $x =~ ^(branches|tags)/$ ]]; then
                      true
                    elif [[ $x =~ ^.*/$ ]]; then
                      #echo "calling checkout $base/$x"
                      checkout $base/$x
                    fi
                  done
   }
```

Use as "checkout myurl"